# No real solutions to $\sum_{n\,=\,0}^\infty \frac {(-1)^{n + 1}} {n^x} = 0$

Tags: summation

Prove that there are no real numbers $x$ such that

$$\sum_{n\,=\,0}^\infty \frac {(-1)^{n + 1}} {n^x} = 0$$

Can I have a hint please?

Comment: What do you know about the error estimates in an alternating series?

Comment: for $x\le0$ the sum diverges, for $x>0$, hmm ... use sqeeze theorem.

Comment: @DanielFischer Nothing, I only know about the alternating series test.

Comment: This is the [Dirichlet $\eta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function).

Comment: Daniel Fischer is correct.  See for example http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/EstimatingSeries.aspx - way down in the document it talks about alternating series, and you can skip most of the rest of this document.

Comment: The $n=0$ term is problematic...  Did you mean $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $x \leqslant 0$, the terms of the series don't converge to $0$, hence the series diverges then. Therefore, we need only consider $x > 0$.

For $x > 0$, the sequence $\left(\frac{1}{n^x}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^+}$ is strictly decreasing and converges to $0$, thus by Leibniz' criterion

$$\eta(x) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^x}$$

converges.

Now, if $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^+}$ is any monotonically non-increasing sequence converging to $0$, we can consider the partial sums of an odd and an even number of terms separately,

$$s_{2p} = \sum_{n=1}^{2p} (-1)^{n+1} a_n;\qquad s_{2p+1} = \sum_{n=1}^{2p+1} (-1)^{n+1} a_n.$$

We find

$$\begin{align}
s_{2p+3} - s_{2p+1} &= (-1)^{2p+3}a_{2p+2} + (-1)^{2p+4}a_{2p+3} = a_{2p+3} - a_{2p+2} \leqslant 0,\\
s_{2p+2} - s_{2p} &= (-1)^{2p+3} a_{2p+2} + (-1)^{2p+2} a_{2p+1} = a_{2p+1} - a_{2p+2} \geqslant 0,\\
s_{2p+1} - s_{2p} &= (-1)^{2p+2}a_{2p+1} = a_{2p+1} \geqslant 0.
\end{align}$$

So

- the sequence of partial sums of an odd number of terms is monotonically non-increasing,
- the sequence of partial sums of an even number of terms is monotonically non-decreasing, and
- the partial sum of an odd number of terms is never smaller than the partial sum of an even number of terms.

If - like for the specific sequence under consideration - the sequence $(a_n)$ is strictly monotonically decreasing, all inequalities above are strict.

It is straightforward to deduce from that that $\eta(x) > 0$ for all $x > 0$.

Answer (score 6):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\sum_{n = \color{#f00}{\LARGE 1}}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n + 1} \over n^{x}} = 0:\
     {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> &\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n + 1} \over n^{x}}
> =\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{{1 \over \pars{2n - 1}^{x}} - {1 \over \pars{2n}^{x}}}
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over 2^{x}}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
> \bracks{{1 \over \pars{n - 1/2}^{x}} - {1 \over n^{x}}} > 0\quad
> \mbox{when}\quad x > 0.\qquad\qquad\mbox{So ?...}
> \end{align}

$\ds{x \leq 0}$ cases are not considered for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1):

This is an observation which is too long for a comment, but which someone will probably appreciate. Remark that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^s} = \zeta(s) - 2\times 2^{-s}\zeta(s) = (1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s).$$

The Riemann zeta function is equal to the Euler product $\prod_p (1-p^{-s})^{-1}$ in the right half-plane $\Re s>1$. The Euler product converges in the sense of [convergence for infinite products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product). A convergent infinite product is never zero, so $\zeta(s)\neq 0$ for $\Re s > 1$. Moreover, it's easy to see that $1-2^{1-s} \neq 0$ for $\Re s> 1$. So we get your result for $\Re s >1$.

For $0<\Re s \leq 1$, it's a little tricky because the Euler product no longer converges. However, your sum is still equal to $(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)$ when $0<\Re s \leq 1$, essentially by analytic continuation. At $s=1$, $(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s) \neq 0$ because the zero of $1-2^{1-s}$ is cancelled by the simple pole of $\zeta(s)$.

Thus, the proofs that Felix and Daniel have given show that the Riemann zeta function doesn't vanish for real $s$ between $0$ and $1$!